# Five words, Five vowels, Five last names

Tags: wordplay, no-computers, english

These five words are from the Collins English Dictionary.

> Are also last names,
>
> And have one vowel difference in exact same location and same
> consonants in exact same locations.

Example :  Last  Lest  List  Lost  Lust

The five words will fit the following sentence:

> Mr. ___ ___ , a farmer, experimented with a new process to turn the
> ___s from his crop into ____ or ____ shapes.

No programming please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A word template that fits nicely here is:

> **B*LL**, giving us [BALL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(surname)), [BELL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_(surname)), [BILL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_(surname)), [BOLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boll_(surname)) and [BULL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bull_(surname)).

And the words can be used in the following order:

> Mr. **BILL BULL**, a farmer, experimented with a new process to turn the **[BOLLs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boll)** from his crop into **BALL** or **BELL** shapes.

The farmer's surname can even be considered pleasantly appropriate considering his occupation :)

Comment: Very nice solve

Answer (score 2):

Alternative Answer

> **D*CK**, giving us [DACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley_Dack), [DECK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deck_(surname)), [DICK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_(surname)), [DOCK](https://www.houseofnames.com/dock-family-crest/Scottish) and [DUCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_(surname)).

And the words can be used in the following order:

> Mr. **DICK DACK**, a farmer, experimented with a new process to turn the **[DOCKs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumex)** from his crop into **[DECK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skateboard#Deck)** or **DUCK** shapes.